# I've created my first language in Irony, now how do I get it into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, irony

I tried [following this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/VSLanguageService.aspx), but I get an error at the end of the wizard. I'm not sure it's compatible with 2010. I'm watching [this video on Ook](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VSIPMarketing/VSX212-Adding-a-Language-Service-into-Visual-Studio-2010), but I'm not sure how to tie it in with Irony. I think Irony's already done a lot of the grunt work for me, I just don't know how to get it to play nicely with `ITaggerProvider` and the 100 other interfaces VS exposes. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you should download the Visual Studio 2010 SDK and read the documentation?

Comment: @John: Gee..thanks. Somehow I don't think the VS2010 SDK docs will have anything to say about Irony, considering Irony wasn't made by MS.

Comment: the SDK docs will say about adding a language service, which it appears you are trying to do.

Comment: @John: Yes, but my question is specifically about how to integrate Irony with it.

Comment: according to the article you linked, Irony is a language service. Anything you read about integrating a language service with Visual Studio will likely also apply to Irony, since it is a language service.

Comment: @John: Not to be pedantic, but Irony isn't a language service, it's a grammar parser/lexer that's used in that article to create a language service.

Comment: Thanks for not being pedantic.

Comment: @John: It's an important distinction. The way you said it makes it sound like I can just run/install it in VS without doing any work because it's already in the right format. Thanks for the help Colin!

Answer (score 3):

- From your template (the zip file) extract the file **IronyLanguageServicePackage.csproj**
- Find the line with the import of *Microsoft.VsSDK.targets* (it should be the 111th line) and change the version of the SDK from v9.0 to v10.0
- Save the file and drag & drop it over the zip template in order to overwrite the old version inside the archive

Now you can use the wizard

Answer (score 2):

Irony is completely compatible with VS2010. I didn't create mine first in VS2010, but migrated my irony based Language Service over from VS2008 though it works just fine. I didn't have to change anything within Irony to get it to work I don't think, and there wasn't much that changed for the project itself.

I found the same article you linked to very useful when I wrote my language service (I started off at the same spot).

The only major changes between that and VS2010 seems to be in distribution. Before you try to do any packaging and installing make sure you test it thoroughly using the experimental hive. It's used exactly how that article describes just the path needs to be to the VS2010 version.

Packaging for install is a bit annoying, but I found this article very useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038.aspx

Other than that there really isn't any magic, that article has you creating a basic language service that interacts with the VS interfaces just fine. It doesn't cover more advanced operations, but you should message out about a specific problem.